# Want to add Sub Menus under "Reports"

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

In odoo I want to add one custom sub menu under the menu `Reports`.(Purchase > Reports )
Reports already contain `Purchase Analysis`.But it is not shown as a drop down list and I can't find the proper `parent id` to add my custom menu `Markup Report` into it.
Somebody please help.
Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: This is your parent Id purchase.purchase_report. you also get id. Open odoo source code -> Odoo --> addons --> purhcase --> report --> open file purchase_report_view and find your parent id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

This solved my problem:

```
<menuitem id="purchase_report_custom" name="Reports" parent="purchase.menu_purchase_root" sequence="99"
        groups="purchase.group_purchase_manager"/>

<menuitem id="purchase_report_analysis" name="Purchase Analysis" parent="purchase.purchase_report" action="purchase.action_purchase_order_report_all"/>

<menuitem action="menu_action_orchid_markup_report" id="markup_report_menu" parent="purchase.purchase_report" name="Markup Report"/>
```

What I have done is created a new top menu `Reports` and put the `Purchase Analysis` and my custom report `Markup Report` inside it.

**Solution 2**

```
<menuitem id="purchase.purchase_report" name="Reporting" parent="purchase.menu_purchase_root" sequence="99" />

<menuitem id = "xn_purchase_analysis" name = "Purchase Analysis"
action="purchase.action_purchase_order_report_all" sequence="1" groups="purchase.group_purchase_manager" parent = "purchase.purchase_report"/>
```

Here I removed the action from 1st menu and created an extra menu and called that action there.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this Code:

**Syntax :**

```
<menuitem id="your_menu_id" name="Your Menu Name" parent="module.parent_menu_id" action="your_menu_action"/>
```

**Example :**

```
<menuitem id="menu_purchase_requisition_purchase" name="Purchase Requisition" parent="purchase.purchase_report" action="purchase_requisition_purchase_action"/>
```

Comment: I tried like this before and tried again , but the problem is my `Purchase Analysis` is getting replaced.(I can't find my `Purchase Analysis`
My code :
<menuitem action="menu_action_orchid_markup_report" id="markup_report_menu" parent="purchase.purchase_report" name="Markup Report"/>

Comment: I got a solution @Bhoomi.. 
Thanks for the help.
I will put my solution under answers.
If you have any other solution,feel free to share.

Comment: thanx for replay @vbt

Comment: Welcome... :-) @Bhoomi